# Improve the speed of t-sne implementation in python for huge data

Tags: python, bigdata, nlp, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I would like to do dimensionality reduction on nearly 1 million vectors each with 200 dimensions(`doc2vec`). 
I am using `TSNE` implementation from `sklearn.manifold` module for it and the major problem is time complexity. Even with `method = barnes_hut`, the speed of computation is still low. Some time even it runs out of Memory.

I am running it on a 48 core processor with 130G RAM. Is there a method to run it parallely or make use of the plentiful resource to speed up the process.

Comment: Did you try map-reduc'ing in a framework like Spark?

Comment: Nope.. how does it work and can you please direct me..

Comment: Pl go through [Spark's documentation](http://spark.apache.org/) for understanding it :)

Comment: See if [this](https://github.com/saurfang/spark-tsne) Spark implementation works.

Comment: @Emre: Which language is used in that implementation ? It seems there is bit of R and scala.. I haven't worked in any of these.. I was looking for python implementation.

Comment: It's Scala for Spark. If you want a python implementation you might be able to translate it; Spark runs on python too.

Comment: @Emre So does it mean I should install `Spark` and compile this `spark-tsne` and then import as a module in python.

Comment: No, it means you should read the Scala package and write one in python based on it. Personally I would advise trying to use the Scala package as is. Although I have no personal experience with, [Beaker](http://beakernotebook.com/features) might help you use Scala and python concurrently. As an alternative to t-SNE, you could one of many python neural network libraries to find a autoencoded 2D embedding.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must look at [this Multicore implementation](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/Multicore-TSNE) of t-SNE.

I actually tried it and can vouch for its superior performance.

Answer (score 8):

Check out FFT-accelerated Interpolation-based t-SNE ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.09005), [code](https://github.com/KlugerLab/FIt-SNE), and [Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fitsne/0.1.10)).

From the abstract:

> We present Fast
>   Fourier Transform-accelerated Interpolation-based t-SNE (FIt-SNE),
>   which dramatically accelerates the computation of t-SNE. The most
>   time-consuming step of t-SNE is a convolution that we accelerate by
>   interpolating onto an equispaced grid and subsequently using the fast
>   Fourier transform to perform the convolution. We also optimize the
>   computation of input similarities in high dimensions using
>   multi-threaded approximate nearest neighbors.

The paper also includes an example of a dataset with a million points and 100 dimensions (similar to OP's setting), and it seems to take ~1 hour.

Answer (score 8):

Try [UMAP](https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap).

It's significantly faster than t-SNE.

Answer (score 6):

Since, there are no answers in SO, I have asked myself in github page and the issue has been closed by stating the following reply by GaelVaroquaux..

> If you only want to parallelise vector operation, then you should use a
>   build of numpy compiled with MKL (don't attempt to do it yourself, it's
>   challenging).
>
> There could be approaches to high-level parallelism in the algorithm
>   itself, which would probably lead to larger gains. However, after a quick
>   look at the code, I didn't see any clear way of doing that.
>
> I am going to ahead and close this issue, as it is more of a blue-sky
>   whish list. I completely agree, I would like TSNE to go faster, and it
>   would be great is parallelism was easy. But in the current state of
>   affairs, more work is required to be in a state where we can tackle such
>   wish list.

Answer (score 3):

Since version 0.22, there is a new parameter called n_jobs in the [scikit-learn t-SNE implementation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html). This parameter specifies the number of parallel jobs to run for neighbors search.

The [Multicore-TSNE](https://github.com/DmitryUlyanov/Multicore-TSNE) project mentioned in another answer seems to be dead.